# Using Hadoop with Cygwin receiving "Error: Could not find or load main class work\work"

Tags: java, hadoop, cygwin

I am using Cygwin on Windows 7 to try and set up a single node in Hadoop 1.2.1.  I am following [this tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html).  I am able to create the input directory fine as well as copy the .xml files to the input directory.  What the trouble seems to be is when I execute `$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs [a-z.]+'` it throws "Error: Could not find or load main class work\work" in the command line.  I have checked the source code (listed below, looks like Python) and there is a main method displayed. I have also tried variations on the original command line call such as,  `$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar main input output 'dfs [a-z.]+'`, etc.

My question is: Why is hadoop not reading this main Method? And how do I get it to read this main method? What is cygwin telling me when it says, "work/work?"Does the fact the source was written in Python and compiled to a .jar format have any significance?

```
from org.apache.hadoop.fs import Path
from org.apache.hadoop.io import *
from org.apache.hadoop.mapred import *

import sys
import getopt

class WordCountMap(Mapper, MapReduceBase):
    one = IntWritable(1)
    def map(self, key, value, output, reporter):
        for w in value.toString().split():
            output.collect(Text(w), self.one)

class Summer(Reducer, MapReduceBase):
   def reduce(self, key, values, output, reporter):
        sum = 0
            while values.hasNext():
            sum += values.next().get()
        output.collect(key, IntWritable(sum))

def printUsage(code):
    print "wordcount [-m <maps>] [-r <reduces>] <input> <output>"
    sys.exit(code)

def main(args):
    conf = JobConf(WordCountMap);
    conf.setJobName("wordcount");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable);

    conf.setMapperClass(WordCountMap);        
    conf.setCombinerClass(Summer);
    conf.setReducerClass(Summer);
    try:
        flags, other_args = getopt.getopt(args[1:], "m:r:")
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        printUsage(1)
    if len(other_args) != 2:
        printUsage(1)

    for f,v in flags:
        if f == "-m":
            conf.setNumMapTasks(int(v))
        elif f == "-r":
            conf.setNumReduceTasks(int(v))
    conf.setInputPath(Path(other_args[0]))
    conf.setOutputPath(Path(other_args[1]))
    JobClient.runJob(conf);

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```